# Rsync doesn't work and reports total size is 0 speedup is 0.00 when the command is run

Tags: rsync

I saw this error and don't know why all file sizes are 0.

[image: screenshot]

Command:

```
rsync -arvzh --delete public/ root@1991421.cn:/var/www/blog/static-html/
```

Version Info:

- GitHub action VM source OS is macOS 10.15
- Target OS is CentOS 7 x64

On my Mac, it's ok, and when I use `scp`, the issue occurs again. So I think it's not a command issue. Maybe it's `ssh`?

Here is my complete config:

```
# This workflow will do a clean install of node dependencies, build the source code and run tests across different versions of node
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/using-nodejs-with-github-actions

name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ source ]
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      logLevel:
        description: 'Log level'
        required: true
        default: 'warning'
      tags:
        description: 'Test scenario tags'
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.20.0]

    steps:
      - name: Git checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: Cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2.1.3
        with:
          path: '**/node_modules'
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-modules-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          yarn install
          npm install hexo-cli@2.0.0 -g
      - name: Build
        run: |
          hexo clean
          hexo g --silent
          export HEXO_ALGOLIA_INDEXING_KEY=fb41a459b46e7dda7af65d45ad5f8432
          hexo algolia
      - name: SSH agent
        uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.4.1
        with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.BLOG_DEPLOY_KEY }}
      - name: Deploy VPS
        run: |
          ssh-keyscan 1991421.cn >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
          rsync -az -vv --delete -e 'ssh -p 22' public root@1991421.cn:/var/www/blog
      - name: Notify
        uses: appleboy/telegram-action@master
        with:
            to: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_TO }}
            token: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_TOKEN }}
            message: Blog deployment and update completed!
            photo: .github/workflows/blog-logo.png
```

Answer (score 1):

### Install an updated version of Rsync in macOS with Homebrew.

I believe this is an issue with the default Rsync version on macOS being out of date due to GNU licensing issues.

The default macOS version of `rsync` exists in this path `/usr/bin/rsync` and has this version when this command is run `/usr/bin/rsync --version`

```
rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29
```

I believe since your paths include non-Western / Chinese characters, this older 2.6.9 version of Rsync is choking on those characters.

You can use a more up-to-date version of Rsync on macOS if you install it via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh). Just install it by opening up a terminal session and entering this command:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Then run this command:

```
brew install rsync
```

Once that command does what it has to do, an updated version of Homebrew should be installed here and you can check the version installed by running `/usr/local/bin/rsync --version` which should be something like this:

```
rsync  version 3.2.3  protocol version 31
```

I used full paths for the version checking, but after that Homebrew install command is run you can just run `rsync --version` to check version and `which rsync` to check which version of Rsync is being preferred by the system.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot, I think most likely it's caused by unrecognized Unicode characters in that folder.

You can try on a folder that doesn't have such characters and see if rsync works.

Comment: but on my mac, it's ok

and when I use SCP, the issue occurs again. so I think it's not a command issue. it's ssh?

Comment: I think by default both RSYNC and SCP utilizes SSH protocol under the hood (though RSYNC is capable of some other protocols), I still tend to think this is more of a character encoding issue, as RSYNC uses different mechanism to determine which files need to be copied over and is less sensitive to encoding.

if you're interested in digging deeper, you can try setting encoding to the right one on both the sending and receiving side (zh_CN.UTF-8, GBK or GB2312, not sure which one is used in your case) and try again. otherwise, you're fine staying with RSYNC, as SCP is considered outdated now.

Comment: regarding SCP considered outdated, here is what the dev team says about it:


>The scp protocol is outdated, inflexible and not readily fixed. We
recommend the use of more modern protocols like sftp and rsync for
file transfer instead.

[link](https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2019-March/037672.html)